# what is API and how I can make it in java programming

Tags: java, swing

I want make a project and I want know what is API and how I can create it in Java?
please need help for creating Api in Java.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: There is no trick on it. An API is basically the set of objects and their interfaces you will expose to another system. There are gazillions types of APIs, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: [API = Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: API is an Application Programming Interface. If you create classes and comment them with JavaDoc, you can automatically create an API that looks like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3):

API is short Application Programming Interface and means the collection of public classes, methods, and fields that you expose to clients (others that use your classes). So whatever you create that you intend to be used by others is API.

(For example, the Swing API would be all the classes and methods from Swing that are intended for use by clients - that is, by you)